# Rails 3.2.x routes being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a weird issue where any get request are being called twice. Here is the log output

First call

```
Started GET "/admin/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-14 17:42:33 -0500
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
```

Second call right after

```
Started GET "/admin/dashboard" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-14 17:42:34 -0500
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as */*
```

Here is my routes output

```
     admin_dashboard_index GET    /admin/dashboard(.:format)                       admin/dashboard#index
                           POST   /admin/dashboard(.:format)                       admin/dashboard#create
       new_admin_dashboard GET    /admin/dashboard/new(.:format)                   admin/dashboard#new
      edit_admin_dashboard GET    /admin/dashboard/:id/edit(.:format)              admin/dashboard#edit
           admin_dashboard GET    /admin/dashboard/:id(.:format)                   admin/dashboard#show
                           PUT    /admin/dashboard/:id(.:format)                   admin/dashboard#update
                           DELETE /admin/dashboard/:id(.:format)                   admin/dashboard#destroy
```

And my routes.rb

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :pages do
      member do
        get 'visual'
      end
    end
    resources :dashboard, :posts, :help
  end
```

Is this normal? It happens in both development and product and as a consequence each GET call is also making a database query.

Update: Adding controller output

Here is my admin/dashboard_controller

```
class Admin::DashboardController < AdminController
  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications
    @has_facebook = @authentications.find_by_provider(:facebook)
    if @has_facebook
      @fb_me = FbGraph::User.me(@has_facebook.token)
      @fb_me.fetch
    end
  end
```

And my admin_controller

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  layout "admin/layouts/application"
end


end
```

And my application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_locale
  before_filter :set_company
  before_filter :subdomain_view_path

  protect_from_forgery

  prepend_view_path "app/views/admin"
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |exception|
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => exception.message
  end

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = I18n.default_locale
  end

  def set_company
    if current_user
      @current_account = current_user.company
      return
    end
    if request.subdomain.present? and request.subdomain != 'www'
      @current_account = Company.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
    else
      if request.domain.present?
        @current_account = Company.find_by_subdomain(request.domain.split('.')[0])
      end
    end
    if not @current_account
      @current_account = Company.find_by_subdomain('default')
    end
  end

  def subdomain_view_path
    if request.subdomain.present? and request.subdomain != 'www'
      prepend_view_path "app/views/#{request.subdomain}_subdomain"
    else
      if request.domain.present?
        prepend_view_path "app/views/#{request.domain.split('.')[0]}_subdomain"
      else
        prepend_view_path "app/views/default_subdomain"
      end
    end
  end

  def check_addon_product
    if @current_account.addons.find_by_title('products')
      return true
    else
      redirect_to root_path, :alert => "Products addon not enabled for this account."
    end
  end

end
```

I suspect im doing something wrong in the application_controller.

Update 2:

So i tried three different methods and all but Google Chrome made the request once. I don't know if this is a known issue or not but thanks to the commenters for pointing me in the right direction.

Update 3:

Found this related bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=39402

Other than providing a favicon is there a way around this?

Comment: looks like the view rendered in two different outputs, can you post up your controller?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't 2 requests coming from the browser? What happens if you request the page with curl? `curl http://localhost:3000/admin/dashboard` Do you get 2 log entries then?

Comment: When i ran curl against the route it show 1 call being made

Comment: hmm i just tested in konqueror (kde browser) and it is showing 1 get request

Comment: well.. it could be either that you are doing the request with the required admin auth in google chrome.. which is why you aren't getting the two request output inclusive of the validation.. it could also be that the admin auth is being stored as a session cookie in chrome which is why maybe ther was a double request made the first time you used chrome to do the same and you couldn't find it later on.